# Softmax function on a column groupby another column in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a **pyspark** dataframe a below:

| Variant | Category | Score | Record |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 915 | 11 | Record-1 |
| A | 907 | 10 | Record-2 |
| A | 914 | 10 | Record-3 |
| B | 914 | 9 | Record-1 |
| B | 907 | 2 | Record-1 |

I want to calculate the softmax score of the `Score` column which is grouped by `Variant` column. this will lead the score for each variant to be total of 100 as below. the Variant can repeat for 3, 2 or 1 time row-wise.

| Variant | Category | Score | Record | Softmax_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 915 | 11 | Record-1 | 0.35 |
| A | 907 | 10 | Record-2 | 0.32 |
| A | 914 | 10 | Record-3 | 0.32 |
| B | 914 | 9 | Record-1 | 0.82 |
| B | 907 | 2 | Record-1 | 0.18 |

I know we have function for softmax in python but not sure how to achieve this is Pyspark.

Softmax formula:

```
def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)
```

Way to do it in Pandas:

```
test['Softmax_Score'] = test.groupby('Variant')['Score'].transform(softmax)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate it the same way in pyspark using functions `exp` and `sum` over a window partitioned by `Variant` like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.withColumn(
    "Softmax_Score",
    F.exp("Score") / F.sum(F.exp("Score")).over(Window.partitionBy("Variant"))
)

result.show()
# +-------+--------+-----+--------+--------------------+
# |Variant|Category|Score|  Record|       Softmax_Score|
# +-------+--------+-----+--------+--------------------+
# |      A|     915|   11|Record-1|   0.576116884765829|
# |      A|     907|   10|Record-2| 0.21194155761708544|
# |      A|     914|   10|Record-3| 0.21194155761708544|
# |      B|     914|    9|Record-1|  0.9990889488055994|
# |      B|     907|    2|Record-1|9.110511944006454E-4|
# +-------+--------+-----+--------+--------------------+
```